# Rails - run a recurring activerecord command on schedule?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command, task

Would appreciate any help getting started on writing a recurring task for a  Rails console activerecord command line. I.e., at 11PM every night I would like to run the following command:

```
Store.all.map { |x| x.update_balance }
```

`update_balance` is a function within the `Store` model. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Essentially you want a cron job, you should check out the [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem.

Comment: What hosting do you use (Heroku etc)?

Comment: whenever gem looks good! host is AWS

Answer (score 1):

Set up a rake task to do the job.  Then, it's just a matter of calling the rake task from some sort of scheduling system.

If you're using a hosting service like Heroku, you will need to use their own scheduler.  If not, you can do it in various ways, but the simplest (assuming you're on a linux/unix/ubuntu etc server) is to use `cron`, which is a built-in scheduler.  See here:  https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/420397:scheduling-magic-intro-to-cron-on-linux

One gotcha with cron is that it runs under it's own user account, rather than the one you log into the server with, which means it might not know about certain variables etc in your environment.  This means that you will need to give it a bit of extra help, for example using the full path to things like bash, ruby and rake.  Here's an example of a scheduled rake task from my cron list, which runs at 3am every day:

```
# m h dom mon dow   command
0 3 * * * /bin/bash -c "source /etc/profile; cd /var/www/apps/myapp/www; /usr/local/bin/rake cached_data:update_all RAILS_ENV=production"
```